# How to set backgroundColor in loadView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I want to override the `loadView` method of my custom view controller in order to customise the view that is being shown. For that custom view I want to apply the background color that was set in the Storyboard editor.

[image]

If I for example implement loadView like this:

```
-(void)loadView{
    self.view = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
    //Do some initialisation work for the custom view
    //...
}
```

Then the resulting view has a black background. However, if I only call the default implementation:

```
-(void)loadView{
    [super loadView];
}
```

Then the orange background color (see screenshot) is applied to the view. How can I get the color that was set in **Storyboard editor**? I would like to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
-(void)loadView{
    self.view = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [self colorThatWasSelectedInStoryboardEditor];
    //Do some initialisation work for the custom view
    //...
}
```

How does apple achieve that in the default implementation of `loadView`?

Comment: Setting the color should be done in `viewDidLoad`, not `loadView`.

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing this in `viewDidLoad`. That would be perfectly fine for me. I just want the background color to be the one that the user has selected in **storyboard editor** (interface builder). As my code above should point out, `loadView` seems to be the place where **Apple's** default implementation applies the color to the view.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do anything? Shouldn't the color be set automatically if you do nothing in the code? I don't use IB so I don't know for sure. But I would think setting things in IB would work if you don't muck it up in code.

Comment: If I don't touch `loadView` then the color is set automatically as expected. However since I want to use `MyCustomView` instead of the default `UIView` I must override `loadView`. And yes, you would think that the background color would be applied automatically even when overriding `loadView`. It WON'T.

Comment: Isn't there a way in IB to tell it that the view should be the custom class? Or is that only for view controllers and not their views?

Comment: You can tell IB that the view is of a custom class but I want to enforce the instantiation of my custom view instead of relying on the user to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Since you apparently really want to use "`loadView`" here instead of "`viewDidLoad`", ***AND*** [Apple's documentation for `loadView` says *NOT* to call "`super`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView), you will need to "hide" your custom color somewhere else.  E.G. some other view (e.g. a hidden one?) in your ViewController, where it's connected to an IBOutlet and where you can extract it via the view's "`.backgroundColor`" property.

Or you will need to set your "`.backgroundColor`" property via good ol' `UIColor` methods like ["`colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a).

Comment: That's not really the point. The question is how can I retrieve the color that was selected in Storyboard editor? In other words how do I implement `[self colorThatWasSelectedInStoryboardEditor]`?

Comment: so you're setting the background color of the view controller's view in your storyboard and it doesn't get applied when the view is displayed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But because the color is indeed applied when not overriding `loadView` I guess I must be missing something in my custom implementation of `loadView`.

Comment: I am not obsessed about using `loadView`. I just cannot see how I would benefit from using `viewDidLoad`. Of course I could set the color programmatically or extract it from another view, but since I am building an open source control for cocoacontrols.com I want to do it properly. I think people would be confused not seeing the background color selected in Storyboard editor being applied. Since the default implementation of `loadView` can do it, I still believe it must be possible to do it somehow in subclasses.

Comment: I'm not 100% what your point of using "`loadView`" is, here... you're defining your view in the storyboard.  Why not just do additional initialization or whatever in your "`viewDidLoad`" method?  The only thing you couldn't do is manually allocate your view controller's view.

Comment: Oh I see what caused the confusion. I DO want to allocate my view manually, since I use a custom view. Also I could add my custom view as a subview of the default view, but since the view will be used in a collection view where performance is a big issue, I don't want to have an intermediate view that I don't really need.

Comment: You can simply set the custom class of your ViewController's view to be your CustomView, within your Storyboard.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it. But then the user also has to connect the delegates to the custom view controller manually to make the control work correctly. I just wanted it to be as simple as possible for the users of my control.

Answer (score 0):

All your views from the Storyboard are laid out before `viewWillAppear:`, which means, in `viewDidLoad` you don't have them yet. Try moving your code to `viewWillAppear:`, or even better, to `viewWill/DidLayoutSubviews` and than `self.view.backgroundColor` will give you the one you set in the IB.

To answer the question in your comment, go to the IB, select your view, go to the Identity Inspector tab under the Utilities (right) pane, and set a custom class to be `MyCustomView`. No need to implement `loadView` to do that.

e.g. a `UIView` that I have declared as a custom view class `AGBlurView`:
[image]

Comment: If I do so, how can I enforce that `MyCustomView` is instantiated instead of a plain `UIView`? That what `loadView` is made for.